# Support différent screen résolutions, density

Tags: android, android-studio, screen, resolution, android-screen-support

i have finished my application but now i see that the layout xml file is not compatible for all smartphone/tablets.
So i did some search and i know that they're different folders for layout wml files and drawables, and the smartphone/tablets gonna pick in the good folders.

For exemple for layout xml files:

```
res/layout-small
res/layout
res/layout-large
res/layout-xlarge
```

That is the good way forthe layout xml files to support all résolutions ?
But how to know which folders is for the 1440 X 2560 screen size ?
And how to name the drawables folders ?

Comment: If you don't care about keeping support for devices below API Level 13, then use the smallest width suffixes introduced in API Level 13. Refer here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.

Comment: @ShubhadeepChaudhuri they dont say whiwh layout folders is for what resolution

Comment: You can only support range of resolutions (which actually makes sense). Create sw600dp for 7" tablets, sw720dp for 10" tablets & the normal layouts for a phone.

Comment: @ShubhadeepChaudhuri its named layout-large or sw600dp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

-For layouts you can specify
 
`res/layout/my_layout.xml`  layout for normal screen size ("default") 
`res/layout-small/my_layout.xml` // layout for small screen size 
`res/layout-large/my_layout.xml` // layout for large screen size 
`res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml` // layout for extra large screen size 
`res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml` // layout for extra large in landscape orientation -- If you want to specify the screen basing on the dp you can spicify the name as

```
res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

-- If you want to specify basing on the smallest width you can specify as

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

For more reference [click here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview)

Comment: So the layouts are for the inches and not the resolution

Comment: The density is the size of a picture ? what is the difference between high density and medium density ?

Comment: you can specify the layouts basing on screen size(inches) and resolutions.

Comment: Density is based on your device real size, if it's small and has a higher resolution, than the density is high cause you show more pixels in less physical space.

Comment: Okay so density = pixels and not the screen size.
Look, Nexus 4/5/6 is redirected for the layout-small directory, and Nexus 4/5/6 have different density (Nexus6:560dpi/Nexus5:xxhdpi/Nexus4:xhdpi) so i don't understand... I Have to do different drawable directory and do different pictures with same sizebut different pixels, thats it ?

Comment: No density is different from pixels. 
Density concerns a relative number of pixels per inch.
You have said that Nexus is redirecting to the layout-small because generally layout-large is for the devices having 7'' inches screen, and layout-xlarge refers to the 10'' inches screen like tablets.

Comment: Generally small,large,xlarge refer screen size and ldpi,mdpi,hdpi and xhdpi refer to screen density.

Comment: I see, but how i do if i want to put biffer pictures for large layouts ?

Comment: You can have drawable folders like 
/res/drawable-large
res/drawable-xlarge
these folders are for 7'' and 10'' inches screens(tablets.)

Comment: Ok si if i do these folder with bigger pictures, the layouts gonna choose automatically the good drawable folders

Comment: ya, android automatically chooses the best drawable folder and picks the image from it,If it doesn't find any drawable then it tries to pick it from other drawable folders.

Comment: Hmm but nos i have  2 folders res/drawable-xlarge and res/drawable, i have put 2 pictures with same name, but when i go on the layout from res/layout-xlarge, the picture is not from res/drawable-xlarge ...

Comment: The src is @drawable/fond_menu so it doesnt choose automatically

Comment: Its wrks, but i don't understand why Nexus 6 goes to small ?

Comment: As i had already said  layout-large is for the devices having 7'' inches screen, and layout-xlarge refers to the 10'' inches screen like tablets,

Comment: Why your picture say large is for between 4 - 7 inches ?

Comment: For normal-layout, only the Nexus 4 can works, i don't understand why

Comment: i have: layout, layout-small, layout-normal, layout-large and layout-xlarge, but theyre a problem: Nexus 4 goes wih layout-small and layout-normal. BUT Nexus One/S/5/6 don't works with layout-small but they do in layout-normal